# Cannot visualize text survey data using online survey dataset

Tags: gis

I just completed an online survey using ArcGIS Survey 123.

A lot of data are strings and categorical data. However, for some reason I cannot explain, whether I open the csv. file in Excel or PowerBI, I could not even produce a basic graph or chart.

For example, I cannot even graph the country regions against main agriculture livelihood type (about 600 respondents).

Here is a screenshot of a portion of the data.

[screenshot of data portion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86bSQ.png)

I would be grateful for any advice on what could possibly be the problem or a step that I am missing.

Many thanks.

Comment: This all seems text values in your raw data. Where is your Measures or Numeric values you wants to plot on the graph? Or, you will generate measures from this source values?

Comment: Thank you, yes, I will generate measures from these source values because most of the survey is qualitative. The rest of the variables are similar to those and would have to be counted, etc. I was hoping that a pivot chart would be able to do these counts but no success so far. So I'm not sure if I'm missing something or doing something fundamentally wrong.

Comment: You have to make your measures (quantitative) first like what is count of Poultry and others. Then you should go for graph and charts. With only qualitative data, you can still create some presentation like table. where you can show the raw data.

Comment: hi, got it. thanks so much, appreciated.